# Having problem displaying date?

Tags: date

I want to display following line:

```
    Current date is: 2013/12/03

    Current time is: 08:50 PM
```

What I have done is:

```
    echo "Current date is:" date +%D



    echo "Current time is:" date +%R
```

But I have not been able to get the answer. So will you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to substitute the value of the command by putting it in `$( ... )`

```
echo "Current date is: $(date +%D)"
```

or using *backticks* (a common older syntax that you will see)

```
echo "Current date is: `date +%D`"
```

See the [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) section of the bash manual

Answer (score 0):

Try also this command on terminal to display date in (year/month/date) format,

```
echo "Current date is:" $(date +'%y/%m/%d')
```

To display time with AM,PM format,

```
echo "Current time is:" $(date +"%r")
```